# How can I make occur's regexp matching case-sensitive?

Tags: occur

By default, occur uses the passed regexp to match lines in a case-insensitive way. Is there a way to make this matching case-sensitive?

For example, if I run `M-x occur ^function RET`, occur will match lines that start with both `function` and `Function`. I want it to only match `function`.

For reference, this is how I am currently using occur to generate a "table of contents" for Perl and other languages:

```
(defun toc ()
  "Show a 'Table of Contents' for the current file using occur"
  (interactive)
  (let (regexp)
    (if (derived-mode-p 'cperl-mode)  ;; for perl
        (setq regexp "^\\(sub\\|has\\|=head1\\|requires\\) ")
      (setq regexp "^function "))     ;; for everything else
    (occur regexp)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `occur` searches are case-insensitive. To force them to be case sensitive, you need to set the variable `case-fold-search` to nil. Note that this is a buffer-local variable. If you set it for one buffer, it won't change it's value for other buffers.

In your function, adding the form `(case-fold-search nil)` to your `let` statement should work:

```el
(defun toc ()
  "Show a 'Table of Contents' for the current file using occur"
  (interactive)
  (let (regexp
        (case-fold-search nil))
    (if (derived-mode-p 'cperl-mode)  ;; for perl
        (setq regexp "^\\(sub\\|has\\|=head1\\|requires\\) ")
      (setq regexp "^function "))     ;; for everything else
    (occur regexp)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may (globally) toggle the behaviour with
`M-x toggle-case-fold-search`.
For more information see http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_list_matching_lines.html (dunno why the emacs wiki is less comprehensive on this topic).